# ws2_32.lib missing from VS2010.What to do?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, sockets, network-programming

I am trying to get my hands on windows socket programming.
I know that you have to `#include winsock2.h`
and then link with `ws2_32.lib`.
Problem is I do not have `ws2_32.lib` in my visual studio 2010 ultimate version.

What should I do to get it up and running?

Secondly, I stumble with integrating new API's in VS 2010 a lot.  I keep on forgetting what to include and what to link and which files are included and which are linked.It would be great if you could point out a tutorial which gives a general procedure in VS 2010 to deal with include and lib files while integrating a new API.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most likely you do have this library but it must be added via Project->Poperties->Linker->Input->additional Dependencies. Type this there:

```
Ws2_32.lib
```

or programmatically:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this I get the following errors:

1>MSVCRTD.lib(crtexew.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
1>C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\dfgdfgh\Debug\dfgdfgh.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Comment: change your main function, do you have main?

Comment: ok It works in a console project.What if I want to do socket programming in win32 project?

Comment: if this is windows application then main for a windows application is called WinMain, you can create another project see how main is called and declared

Comment: you create win32 project and also import this lib, just don't mess up main functions