# Linker Error (LNK2019) undefined reference to __imp_

Tags: c, dll, cmake, linker, opc-ua

I am working on open62541 open source project.I have built the project using Cmake as mentioned here at the following webpage [open62541.org](https://open62541.org/doc/current/building.html) and generated the open62541.c ,open62541.h files in the project's build folder.Then I created a new folder called **C_project** inside the build folder and copied the generated files into this folder.

Now I am trying to build a minimal server(C_Project/myServer.c)  by following the steps given at the following page [open62541/sever](https://open62541.org/doc/current/tutorial_server_firststeps.html).I am getting the following link errors.

```
C:\SPB_Data\open62541\build\C_Projects\OPC_UA>cmd /c gcc -std=c99 open62541.c myServer.c -lws2_32 -o myServer.exe > output.txt
C:\Users\PAVAN-~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc1s9pOw.o:myServer.c:(.text+0x98): undefined reference to `__imp_UA_ServerConfig_setMinimalCustomBuffer'
C:\Users\PAVAN-~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc1s9pOw.o:myServer.c:(.text+0xd8): undefined reference to `__imp_UA_Log_Stdout'
C:\Users\PAVAN-~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc1s9pOw.o:myServer.c:(.text+0x132): undefined reference to `__imp_UA_Server_new'
C:\Users\PAVAN-~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc1s9pOw.o:myServer.c:(.text+0x146): undefined reference to `__imp_UA_Server_getConfig'
C:\Users\PAVAN-~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc1s9pOw.o:myServer.c:(.text+0x165): undefined reference to `__imp_UA_Server_run'
C:\Users\PAVAN-~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc1s9pOw.o:myServer.c:(.text+0x178): undefined reference to `__imp_UA_Server_delete'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

[image: Linker errors]

I used the following command to build the project:

```
$ gcc -std=c99 open62541.c myServer.c -o myServer
```

I tried to find the solutions for this by searching in the web. The only thing that I could get out of that is it might be a error due to dll files. Kindly help.

Comment: Those errors would be much easier to read if you pasted them in as text.

Comment: Why do you use `> output.txt` at the end of the command line? You probably want to see all output of the compiler/linker, both in stderr and stdout.

Comment: To output the results to the text file

Comment: In my case this solution helped :
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16104823/17493620)

Answer (score 1):

**`-open62541.lib` specifies that the result of compilation should be written to file *`pen62541.lib`***.

And `-o myServer.exe` says that it should be written to `myServer.exe` instead.

And GCC will then ignore the first output file name.

Solution: remove the `-` from the library name.

Comment: Tried it.Did not solve the error.The command mentioned in the open62541.org webpage is `gcc -std=c99 open62541.c myServer.c -lws2_32 -o myServer.exe` , i added the `-open62541.lib`.Nevertheless ,I get errors for both

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem as you when I made the CMake build with BUILD_SHARED_LIBS on.
For me it was working when I installed open62541 with CMake options UA_ENABLE_AMALGAMATION on and UA_NAMESPACE_ZERO full (rest default)

I compiled with the command

```
gcc -std=c99 myserver.c open62541.c -o server -lws2_32
```

Inside the selected folder are just the files open62541.c/.h and myserver.c